# Load local dll with node-ffi: No such file

Tags: javascript, dll, node-ffi

I try to load a local .dll according the examples on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802642/using-a-dll-with-node-ffi) and [node-ffi documentation](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial).
But I get the error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../test/user32.dll.so'. The file is there (no exception).
The extension '.so' is added automatically. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is this code plattform dependent? I'm on Debian.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const ffi = require('ffi');

function setCursor() {
    const dllFile = path.join('../test', 'user32.dll');
    if (!fs.existsSync(dllFile)) {
        throw (new Error('dll does not exist'));
    }

    const user32 = ffi.Library(dllFile, {
        "SetCursorPos": [
            "bool", ["int32", "int32"]
        ]
    });

    console.log(user32.SetCursorPos(0, 0));
}

setCursor();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like path doesn't recognize `../test` as being the parent folder. I think `path.join(__dirname, '..', 'test', 'user32.dll');` should get you to the right place.